# How to define images for template on every page?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

i built up a wordpress theme and inserted an imageslider to this. The Images are still static but i would like to define them on every wordpress-page. I may could filter the page ID in the template-header and define the images dynamically.

Now im searching for a method to dynamically define them in the pageeditor in the backend of wordpress. So that the customer can change them himself for every page.
Is there already a plugin for this problem or any other easy solutions?

thanks and greatings

stetro

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is some great slider plugins already out there. [WooThemes's one](http://www.woothemes.com/wooslider/) being one of my favourite. It is $35 though.

If you've already got it all setup though, and just need to be able to do it dynamically, then you could use a plugin like [Attachments](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/attachments/faq/). You can just have it call the attachments for the current page/post, and use those images. If you NEED to have a slider on every page, then check for attachments on the current page/post, and if there is none, then request the ones for the home page. Done and done. Well I hope so, not sure if I read your question correctly... Hope this helps but :)

Comment: Thank you for the great answer ! :-) Is it possible to predefine attachment propaties like imagesize or "only images" ?

Comment: So you don't need me to answer the first comment?

Comment: I could not found any mimetype restrictions and imagesize propaties. If you have any solution, it would be great. Otherwise it's ok like this :-)

Comment: You can check the mime type it gives you in an if statement, and here is a link to customise Wordpress image sizes: http://wp.tutsplus.com/tutorials/theme-development/using-custom-image-sizes-in-your-theme-and-resizing-existing-images-to-the-new-sizes/